# Delete the PDF after creating it in the Temp folder and opening it

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I want to convert the binary code into a file in the temp folder and open the file and after opening, delete the file, but I don't want the file to be accessible from a way other than the program.

I was able to save the binary code to a PDF file in the temp folder (I think that saving with the PDF extension is not the right way) but I don't know how to open the file and delete it after opening.

PDF creation code:

```
                string binaryCode=".....";
                string tempName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                string fileLocation = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), tempName + ".pdf");
                int numOfBytes = binaryCode.Length / 8;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[numOfBytes];
                for (int i = 0; i < numOfBytes; ++i)
                {
                    bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(binaryCode.Substring(8 * i, 8), 2);
                }
                File.WriteAllBytes(fileLocation, bytes);
```

My project works using .net 6.

Comment: Can you explain why not allowing other to access it

Comment: Because some users should not copy pdf and can only see it

Comment: Regarding user permissions if 
Your users are logged in with in active directory, you can save the file with system permissions so user can not open the file. If not there is no other solutions. You can eventually password protect the pdf.

Comment: Assuming that users can copy the PDF or ... what should I do so that the file is opened and then deleted after closing?(the program must be able to run while the PDF is open)

Answer (score 0):

You can open it with Process, then delete it :

```
using System.Diagnostics;

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName);
Process.Start(startInfo);
File.Delete(fileName);
```

But I don't see how you want to avoid people to have the PDF, they still can use "save as" from the viewer I guess.

Comment: What can I do so that the file cannot be accessed by anyone other than the program?

Comment: @sima you cannot, except if you find a `PDF_Viewer` that you could include in your project, I don't know if it exists for free.

Comment: @sima I found that if this could help : https://www.pdfprinting.net